# Texture argument in the Line class

Tags: graphics, kivy

In this Kivy garden Plot module, a [`texture` parameter is passed](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/__init__.py#L998) to a `Line()` constructor, and subsequently used for anti-aliasing. I couldn't find any documentation on this argument in the [official docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line). From looking at the [source of `Line`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions_line.pxi#L119), it looks like this parameter is not parsed altogether.

Is this a legacy parameter? If so, how was it used and how can this functionality be achieved now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because the SmoothLinePlot is using a custom fragment shader, defined [here](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/__init__.py#L960). This uses the information in the texture to achieve the antialiasing effect.

The normal Line actually *does* use the texture (actually all VertexInstructions can take a texture parameter and have vertices including texture coordinates), but in a trivial way that doesn't work for more than this antialiasing, and isn't taken advantage of by kivy's [default fragment shader](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/glsl/default.fs). This actually is covered in the source of Line, the texture property is checked [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions_line.pxi#L273), and the information about what texture coordinates to use is set when constructing the vertices later, e.g. [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions_line.pxi#L412).

Assuming you're using kivy master (some of these changes are recent, the Line used to only parse the (0,0) coordinate of the texture), I think you should be able to see this in action by assigning a texture to any line. I'm not sure what effect you'll see, as the texture is mapped along line segments, not the whole line, and in a way that may not give visual consistency.